# How do I mix "absolute" and relative urls in Angular2?

Tags: css, url, angular

There are (at least?) 2 ways of specifying urls for the `templateUrl` and `styleUrls` properties of Component decorators in Angular2:

1. "absolute" or, more precisely, relative to the project root (the default), and
2. relative to the current document/component.

The latter is accomplished by using component-relative paths, i.e. by including `moduleId: module.id` in the decorator.

But how do I combine the two? For example, I want to use two different style files for one component:

1. one that is used generally for my whole project

   - `my-general-project-styles.css` in the example below
   - file location should be relative to the project root (e.g. directly *in* the project root) so that many files in different locations can access it in its central location
2. one that is specific for my current component

   - `my-specific-component.styles.css` in the example below
   - file location should be relative to the current file/component so that the file and its associated styles (and templates, etc.) can be moved around easily

e.g.:

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id, // I'm not sure if I should still use this
    template: '<h1>My Component</h1>',
    styleUrls: ['my-general-project-styles.css', 'my-specific-component-styles.css']
})
export class MyComponent {}
```

By the way, I'm using the commonjs module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out to be simpler than I expected...just put a '/' in front of the url that you want to be relative to the project root, e.g.

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    template: '<h1>My Component</h1>',
    styleUrls: ['/my-general-project-styles.css', 'my-specific-component-styles.css']
})
export class MyComponent {}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution does not work for me. I use angular 2.0.3 - Any changes since your post?

Does **not** work:

```
@Component({
moduleId: module.id,
selector: "process-list",
templateUrl: "processList.component.html",
styleUrls: ["/Content/processList.css"]
})
```

Works:

```
@Component({
moduleId: module.id,
selector: "process-list",
templateUrl: "processList.component.html",
styleUrls: ["../../../Content/processList.css"]
})
```